# How do i remove all occurences of semicolon from the end of all lines?

Tags: sed

These are the steps i am following.

```
`sed 's/[;]+$//g'`
```

also

```
  sed 's/;{1,\}$//g'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In basic regular expression you have to escape the `+` quantifier:

```
sed 's/;\+$//' file
```

Or use extended regular expression (if your `sed` supports them; GNU `sed` does):

```
sed -r 's/;+$//' file
```

Comment: There's no `\+` in standard BRE, GNU BREs and a few others have it as an extension though. With standard BREs, `+` is written `\{1,\}`. In this case though, `*` will work just as well. `sed 's/;*$//'`. Some `sed` implementations support EREs with the `-E` option (which IMO makes more sense than `-r`).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, to get the exact `+` meaning would be `sed 's/;;*$//'`, but that makes no real difference here.

Answer (score 1):

I doesn't work if the file is with CRLF line terminators. To make it work you have to combine with the conversion :

`sed 's/.$//'`